# Telegram bot. How do I print DataFrame in telegram message?

Tags: python, telegram, py-telegram-bot-api

So I'm making my first telegram bot using pyTelegramBotApi.
The thing is: my bot contains a pandas DataFrame in it. And when user sends some special text to bot, bot needs to send this DataFrame to user.
I was doing it by converting DataFrame to a string value:

```
table = df.to_string(columns = ['Name', 'Description'], index = False, header = False, line_width = 70, justify = 'left')

bot.send_message(message.chat.id, table)
```

(Also I can't align it left, it always gets centered)

Is there any other way to do that?

Comment: are you getting any errors? or do you just not like how the message looks?

Comment: No, it works fine, besides the alignment (so I kind of don't like how it looks). Also I didn't yet tried it with big cells containing ~100 symbols. So I thought maybe there is better and more optimal solution

Answer (score 0):

In the below code, I use **"parse_mode" is HTML**, in fact I did the same yesterday:

```
 var HTML = '<b>Top Brackets</b>\n-------------------------------------------------------------\n
                                  Type   Name      Class          Total
                                  \n-------------------------------------------------------------\n';
                  var data = response.data;
                  for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                        // $.sendMessage('<b>I am Bold</b>\n<i>I am italic</i>',{parse_mode: "HTML"});
                        HTML += `<b>${data[i].type}</b>    ${data[i].name}}    ${data[i].class}%   ${data[i].total_unit}\n`
                  }
                  HTML +='\n\nUpdated 3 sec ago.\nWebiste : www.abc.com';
                  $.sendMessage(HTML,{parse_mode: "HTML"});
                  //bot.sendMessage(id,HTML,{parse_mode: "HTML"}) /*THE IMPORTANT ONE */
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Didn't try that yet, I will when I get to my PC. Is it C++?

Comment: @kekundel, No bro its not C++ code, its javascript code, But i am pretty much sure it works fine. You can convert the syntax in your own programming language.